# remove blank lines from for loop python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have numerous lines getting printed out in python from for loops like below:

```
class Wordnet():

    def compose_line6(self, pointers, pointers_synset_type):    
        for A, B in zip(pointers, pointers_synset_type):
            self.line6 += 'http://www.example.org/lexicon#'+A+' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos '+B+'\n'
        return self.line6

    def compose_line7(self, pointers, pointer_source_target):
        for A, B in zip(pointers, pointer_source_target):
            self.line7 += 'http://www.example.org/lexicon#'+A+' http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target '+B+'\n'
        return self.line7
```

The '\n' is there so that the for loops don't just get printed out in a big block, but this also add a blank line to the end of each loop. printing these at the moment using this method:

```
def compose_contents(self, line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6, line7):
    self.contents = '\n'.join([line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6, line7])
    return self.contents
```

and printing `self.contents` gives this:

```
http://www.example.org/lexicon#13796604 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos n
http://www.example.org/lexicon#00603894 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos a
http://www.example.org/lexicon#00753137 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos v
http://www.example.org/lexicon#01527311 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos v
http://www.example.org/lexicon#02361703 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#pos v

http://www.example.org/lexicon#13796604 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0000
http://www.example.org/lexicon#00603894 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0401
http://www.example.org/lexicon#00753137 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0302
http://www.example.org/lexicon#01527311 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0203
http://www.example.org/lexicon#02361703 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#source_target 0101
```

How do avoid the blank line in the middle of the print()?

EDIT: all of these methods are called in a for loop 
    def line_for_loop(self, file):
        for line in file:
            self.compose_line6(self.pointers, self.pointers_synset_type)
            self.compose_line7(self.pointers, self.pointer_source_target)
            self.compose_contents(self.line1, self.line2, self.line3, self.line4, self.line5, self.line6, self.line7)

and the print is `print wordnet.contents`

Comment: How compose_contents is called?

Comment: Have you tried using ''.join(...) instead of '\n'.join(...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out empty lines:

```
def compose_contents(self, *lines):
    self.contents = '\n'.join([line for line in lines if line.strip()])
    return self.contents
```

This supports an arbitrary number of input lines by using the `*args` arbitrary positional argument syntax.